# How to use log4j in Embedded JDK compact 1/2/3

Tags: java, log4j, embedded, java-8

I try to port existing Java project into embedded environment. But I found log4j-1.2.14 could not work under such environment. Since it has dependency with Beans.

I build the EJDK8 compact 2 environment. More information about EJDK8: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/resources/tech/compact-profiles-overview-2157132.html

When start the project, it has the following exceptions.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/beans/IntrospectionException
     [java]     at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:649)
     [java]     at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:612)
     [java]     at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:509)
     [java]     at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415)
     [java]     at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:441)
     [java]     at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:470)
     [java]     at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.(LogManager.java:122)
     [java]     at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
     [java]     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
     [java]     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
     [java]     at com.truviso.system.Application.(Application.java:36)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.beans.IntrospectionException
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     [java]     ... 11 more

After reading log4j source code, I found there are many dependencies with java.beans.*. The the beans namespace is not supported by EJDK. In this case, what kinds logging framework we could use? The log4j is widely used in many libraries. Do we have some other choices?

Answer (score 3):

> In this case, what kinds logging framework we could use? The log4j is widely used in many libraries. Do we have some other choices?

Well, `java.util.logging` is in the compact1 profile, so that is an obvious candidate.

But if you are using a library that depends directly on log4j, then you are kind of stuck.  You either need to "butcher" log4j (bad idea), or you need to change the library's logging framework.  If you do the latter, consider changing it to `slf4j` ... which will allow you to use a variety of "back end" logging frameworks, depending on your application or platform requirements.

Comment: I see. But I found there are thousands of files which has dependency with log4j. I have a workaround to fix log4j now. Log4j depends java.beans to read the properties file. So I could configure log4j programmatically. But next I found the common-configuration depends on common-jxpath who has dependency with java.beans.FeatureDescriptor. My God.

Comment: @Yiming - life is like that.  :-(  You are among the first people trying to use a raft of 3rd party libraries on a new platform ("compact" Java) that they weren't developed for.  Bleeding edge.

Comment: I try to build my own compact JRE. I will weave some beans code into standard compact2 JRE. I found quite a lot dependency with beans package.

Comment: After adding java.bean.*, com.sun.beans.* and javax.xml.bind.*. Now my JRE works. The total size is still 15MB. The only tricky part is we need update meta-index to enable the above namespace.

Comment: @Yiming Can you please answer your own question with your solution( adding java.bean.*, etc )? Others might want to know how to get log4j working with java se embedded - compact2

Answer (score 2):

The jrecreate build tool based on some profile to provide the jre to use in your application. You can select the smallest footprint as compact1, compact2 and compact3 and test your application.
But sometimes some applications need to access more resources, the options above are:

--vm server or all being size much higher.

My case resolved with --vm server, dependency using java/beans/IntrospectionException.

Solution alternative:

```
$ cd ejdk1.8.0_51
$ export JAVA_HOME=linux_i586/jre
$ ./bin/jrecreate.sh --vm server --dest version-server-jre8

Building JRE using Options {
ejdk-home: /home/bueno/Downloads/ejdk1.8.0_51
    dest: /home/bueno/Downloads/ejdk1.8.0_51/version-server-jre8
    target: linux_i586
    vm: server
    runtime: jre
    debug: false
    keep-debug-info: false
    no-compression: false
    dry-run: false
    verbose: false
    extension: []
}

Target JRE Size is 49.379 KB (on disk usage may be greater).
Embedded JRE created successfully
```

More information: docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/

Answer (score 1):

This way seems to work:

Create a new "full profile" with jrecreate (defaults to making a full profile when no parameter is given.)

Copy java/bean and com/sun/beans from the full/lib/rt.jar to your compact profile /lib/rt.jar

edit the /lib/meta-index file and add the line "/com/sun/beans" (again, you can have a look at the "full" meta-index file and copy the line)